# Downloading a file from a SQL Database using Silverlight

Tags: sql, silverlight

I'm trying to develop a Silverlight application that will download a specified file from a SQL database. I'm aware Silverlight can not do this independently, so I am wondering as to what the best way to accomplish this is.

The website that the Silverlight app will run on is asp.net with C# code behind.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to run a web application or service to grab the data. You could have the Silverlight application query the web app for the needed data which would trigger the app to query the database. You would program the web app to return the data in whatever format you needed, JSON, XML, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to write a simple [Asp.Net Handler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001). The other would be to expose the download functionality via a WCF Service. If this download functionality would be implemented as WCF Rest Service, even non WCF Clients would be able to download the file.

Comment: Do you have any references? I've been looking into WCF services, but haven't found anything applicable to a SQL database.